# Integrating fonts

Tags: css, jsf-2, fonts

I'm integrating css to my JSF2 application and something isn't working with the fonts. This is how I try it:

The fonts are in WebContent/resources/fonts (on Eclipse.) In the same directory I have a stylesheet.css file, and I declare the font face like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'TitilliumText22LRegular';
src: url('titilliumtext22lregular-webfont.eot');
src: url('titilliumtext22lregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('titilliumtext22lregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('titilliumtext22lregular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('titilliumtext22lregular-webfont.svg#TitilliumText22LRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

I connect to the stylesheet with this in the header.xhtml of my application:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="fonts" name="stylesheet.css"/>
```

The css class element that tries to connect to this is in resources/css and is called style.css. The class itself:

```
.time {
    font: 19px 'TitilliumText22LRegular';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.8;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

For all I can tell this should work. But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with JSF. It is pure CSS.
I would check (with any HTTP traffic sniffer tool) if your font files are accessible for browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried not using the shorthand font? Try just using `font-family: 'TitilliumText22LRegular';` and see what happens?

Comment: Actually, hcharge, now the font is found, but it seems like the size doesn't catch. So in font-family:10px 'TitilliumText22LMedium'; the 10px has no effect. I can do 48, or 8, it's always the same size (seems like 22...) Any idea?

Comment: you need to add the font-size separately... so it would be 

font-family: 'TitilliumText22LRegular';
font-size: 10px;

Comment: because you're no longer using the shorthand property you'd need to add each one after the other, like font-style, font-weight... etc.